# Polynomial with a prime number as a root

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

Is it possible to prove that this equation is false:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n a_i p^i = 0
$$

with following conditions:

$a_i \in [-1;1]$; [Might $a\in\{-1,1\}$ have been intended here?] 
$p$ is a prime number; 
$n > 0$.

Comment: Might you have meant $a\in[-1,1]$ or "$a$ is in $[-1,1]$" where you wrote "$a$ is $[-1,1]$"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The first option

Comment: @Sofia You didn't have to choose: $a\in[-1,1]$ and $a$ is in $[-1,1]$ means the same.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: $a\in[-1,1]$ means the same as "$a$ is in $[0,1]$". I suspect the OP meant to say "$a_i \in \{-1,1\}$". At least that makes the statement true!

Comment: @TonyK : I now suspect you're right.  Six answers have appeared so far, and not all of them construe the question that way. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Indeed! Three of those answers show that the statement is false as written; of the other three, two of them assume $a_i \in \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: And if ai value is exactly -1 or 0 or 1 (all of them can't be 0). Is it possible to prove that F(p) can't be 0?

Comment: @Sofia: Then Robert Israel's answer applies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies!

Comment: This isn't really a property of primes, just of $x\geq 2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What **is** true is that if $a_n = 1$, $p \ge 2$ and all $a_i \in [-1,1]$, then
$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i p^i > 0$.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you meant $a_i \in \{-1,1\}$. The same argument works if $ a_n = \pm 1$ and the rest of the $a_i$'s are in the interval $[-1,1]$ or even more generally if $\vert a_ n\vert \geq \vert a_i \vert$ for all $i \in \{0,1,2\ldots,n-1\}$.

If so, assume what you have is true and we will obtain a contradiction.

We have
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i p^i = - a_n p^n$$
This gives us
$$\left \vert \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i p^i \right \vert = \left \vert - a_n p^n \right \vert = p^n$$
since $\vert -a_n \vert = 1$. We have
$$p^n = \left \vert \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i p^i \right \vert \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left \vert a_i p^i\right \vert = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p^i = \dfrac{p^n-1}{p-1} \leq p^n-1$$
which gives us a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

$$0.01p-0.03=0$$

Answer (score 1):

No. $p=2$, $n = 1$, $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = -\frac 12$ gives 
$$ a_0 + a_1p^1 = 1 -\frac 12 \cdot 2 = 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=1$, $a_n=-\frac1p$, $a_0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $a_i \in \{-1, 1\}$ then you can just use the rational root's test to show that the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1$.